# I cant use sin, cos or acos functions in Doctrine in a Symfony 4's project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have this Select:

```
$consulta = $em->createQuery("SELECT s.centro_turistico AS centro_turistico, 
    s.provincia AS provincia, s.region AS region, 
    s.latitud AS latitud, s.longitud AS longitud, 
    ((acos((sin('$latitud1' * 0.01745329252) * sin(latitud * 0.01745329252)) + (cos('$latitud1' * 0.01745329252) * cos(latitud * 0.01745329252) * cos(('$longitud1' - longitud) * 0.01745329252))) * 57.29577951308) * 111.302) as distancia
    FROM App:TablaEnlacesCentros s");
```

and it gives me:

> Error: Expected known function, got 'acos'

I tried this:
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Define the property you want to use in the configuration file. Add Config Parameters:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                field: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Field
                name: NameSpace vs..
```

https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/config/mysql.yml

Comment: I've https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/config/mysql.yml file in my config dir, but it doesnt work. In my repository file I write: use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader;
require '/var/www/symfony/argentina/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', '/var/www/symfony/argentina/vendor/beberlei/src/Query/Mysql');
$classLoader->register();

Comment: manually add the package you want to use to the config/packages/doctrine.yml file.

Comment: Thank you Ramazan Apaydın. I add the custom class in doctrine.yaml file, and now it works fine.